# JDBC compatible Main Memory Standalone database

Tags: java, jdbc, main-memory-database

I need a high performance main memory database for my Java Application

1] Please suggest the database which is
     **-JDBC compliant

     -Standalone(i.e. Flat-File)

     -supporting memory tables

     -High performance

     -B-TREE indexing**

2] Is there any technique in JAVA to load the database in **MEMORY** while the program is running and store it back to disk (**in compressed format**) when program exists.

Please DO NOT suggest SQLITE since performance is the issue.

If you are suggesting HSQLDB or H2 with in-memory mode then tell me the way to store the database in a file and free the HEAP with the actionEvent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for in-memory then [JavaDb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) will likely be of use. However, you also refer to flat files, and I'm a little confused by this. Perhaps you want something like [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/), which puts a JDBC interface over a `.csv` implementation.